# Why this work only once?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

```
public class Main {

private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int port = 13579;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Servidor Iniciado escuchando al puerto " + port);
        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String request = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            String returnMessage = "";
            if (request.startsWith("ISO0060000500800")) {
                returnMessage = "ISO006000050081082200000020000000400000000000000" + request.substring(48, 64) + "00" + request.substring(64);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received: " + request);
                try {
                    InterpretePostilionEvertec interpretePostilionEvertec = new InterpretePostilionEvertec();
                    Transaccion transaccion = interpretePostilionEvertec.interpretarRequest(request);
                    GestorTransacciones gestorTransacciones = new GestorTransacciones();
                    try {
                        returnMessage = interpretePostilionEvertec.interpretarResponse(gestorTransacciones.abono(transaccion), request);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    returnMessage = "Error: " + e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(returnMessage);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("Return: " + returnMessage);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

The first message i receive from client A its ok, but when he tries to send me another one, is never accepted. Is stuck at socket = serverSocket.accept();
What im i doing wrong? please help me :D

**I Need to keep alive the session. The first string i receive is like and echo or aknowlage, the second one is the actual request.

Comment: add another loop to read multiple messages after  socket = serverSocket.accept();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only reads one request per accepted connection. You need an inner loop, or better still start a separate thread to handle each accepted connection, in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
/**
 * Continuously listen on port 8888. accept() will block
 * until a new connection is requested. When a new connection 
 * is received, spawn a new thread to service it, 
 * then listen for more.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8888);
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try {
        while (true) {
            es.submit(new SomeObject(listener.accept()));
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
        es.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

where SomeObject implements Runnable

Answer (score -1):

I think you should accept connection from the same client one time only. you already have the socket read from it as much as you want. use accept when you get new connection from another client.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. Possibly you need to express it more clearly. I can see the germ of a correct answer in there but it isn't clear that you meant it :-|